# Rotation of a square/rectangle around a point

Tags: geometry, rotations, plane-geometry

this is the first time I ask a question here. I want to know what's the simplest way of calculating the coordinates for the 4 points of a square/rectangle on a plane, after a rotation around a point, given an angle.

[Example of the rotation of a square.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePAIP.png)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). After rotation by an angle $\theta$, the coordinates of a point $(x,y)$ are
$$\pmatrix{\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\\x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta}.$$
Now compute that for the points of interest. For example, if the square is centered on $(R,0)$ and its side length is $2r$, then the upper left corner is at $(R-r, r)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ (x,y)= a ( \cos \theta, \sin \theta) + \frac{b}{\sqrt2} [ (\cos(2k-1)\pi/4+ \theta), (\sin(2k-1)\pi/4+ \theta)] $$

where $a,b$ are circle radius and side of square respectively, $k=(1,4,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the equations for polar form: $r\cos\theta = x$ and $r\sin\theta = y$? These formulas will help you here.

Given a square, you can find the distance from any vertex to the origin ($r$) using Pythagorean theorem. You will know $x$ and $y$ because of the graph. Then, it's a matter of finding $\theta$.

Once this is done, all rotations are simply a matter of adding degrees to $\theta$. If you want to find the coordinates in Cartesian again, then simply use the above transformation equations.

Comment: Given a square, you can find its distance from the origin.  From which point of the square are we measuring distance to the origin?

Comment: From the vertex; just added that.

Comment: The point that would serve best is the center of the square, where its diagonals meet.

Comment: Well, @OP asked for how to find the corners of the square when it was rotated.

Comment: The exact coordinates of the vertices can easily be found given the rotation of the center of the square given the rotation about the circle (radius being center of the square from origin)

Comment: True, but it's not like either method doesn't work.